# Intersection Observer with positive 'rootMargin' not working as expected

Tags: ionic-framework, intersection-observer

I am attempting to use Intersection Observer to do some lazy loading od data elements in an app. I am attempting to use the `rootMargin` option to have the Intersection Observer called well before the items enter the page so that some api calls to load data can take place before the items become visible. However adding values to `rootMargin` is not working to accomplish the objective.

I put together a little test app that has a list of 100 items.

Here is the output from Intersection Observer when there is no `rootMargin`:
[image]

As you can see in this scenario there were six intersecting entries and 94 non intersecting entries which correctly matches the six entries that were visible on the page. This is correct with a `rootMargin` of 0.

I then set the bottom `rootMargin` to 400px which should have increased the number of intersecting entries, but it did not. Here is the output from the logs after changing the `rootMargin`:
[image]

As you can see the number of intersecting entries did not change.

Here is the log output from one of the non intersecting entries from the Intersection Observer callback:

[image]

It is confusing to me as to why this entry is showing as non intersecting. The top and bottom of the `boundingClientRec` are within the top and bottom of `rootBounds` so it would seem that the item should be considered intersecting. Also, the height of `rootBounds` does reflect the 400px that were added in `rootMargin`.

What is also confusing is if I put a negative amount in `rootMargin` it correctly reduces the number if intersecting entries.

Here is a link to the test app on Stackblitz:
[Click here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-rg4p6g-drdlx7)

Any help would be appreciated.